# Newton's Law of Cooling and General advice on modeling with ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have a question that goes as follows:

For this question, assume that turkeys follow Newton’s law of cooling/heating.
I start my oven heating at 12pm. The temperature
of the oven increases linearly with time until it reaches 150C at
12.30pm. The oven is initially at room temperature, 20C.

a. Write an equation for the temperature of the oven as a function
of t, the time in hours since 12pm.

b. A turkey is placed in the oven at 12pm. The relaxation time
of the turkey is 1 hour. (Hint: this means that the constant in
Newton’s law is ± 1/hour depending on your sign convention).
The temperature of the turkey at 12pm is 4◦C. Find the temperature
of the turkey at 12.30pm (leave powers of $e$ as part of your
answer).

I know the question for this answer but I am having trouble doing the problem without it given that I cant quite associate the separate objects together. It seems that this is a general problem for me with differential equations, which is that I am really struggling to come up with an equation for some word problem that is given while, on the other hand, solving it afterwards is not really much of a problem. The most annoying thing is that I don't seem to see many practical application problems in textbooks (especially the one I am using).

Could someone offer up some advice for this problem and in general please ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "I know the question for this answer "? I'd like to give some advice, but I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, I meant that the answer is provided but I want to know the process and thought details for questions like these.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I'm not feeling well now, but I'll circle back and try to provide an answer in a couple of days.